# Open Powershell in ConEmu from context window

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, powershell, context-menu, conemu

I would like to open Powershell inside ConEmu from Windows Explorer's context menu so that it contains the same directory as Windows Explorer.

I know about the "Integration" settings, but I cannot figure out what "Command" I should use to get Powershell to open at the same directory as Windows Explorer. In other words, when I click on "Open in Powershell" on my context menu, I would like it to open ConEmu with Powershell already at the same directory as I was in Windows explorer without having to copy/paste the path manually into my console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works perfectly without any special steps. And what I'm doing wrong?

[image: ConEmu Integration Settings]
[image: Explorer context menu]
[image: Started PowerShell tab]

Check your $profile, use ProcessExplorer and ProcessMonitor to check parameters of started processes.